# How to return JS value using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myHref').change(function(){
        var value = $('#myHref').val();
        $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
        { 
        .....
        .....
        if(condition here){}
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

I need to check a condition according to the value returned from get_projectName.php. Let get_projectName.php have `$abc = 1;` and according to this value I need to use if condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `jquery` condition will be totally depend on the type of data returned from the `php` function. Let's check for the example:-

**Example 1 :-**

**If your `php` code is :-**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){ // check id coming from `ajax` or not
  $data = 1; // as you said
}
echo $data;
?>
```

**Then `jquery` will be:-**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script><!-- library needed-->
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myHref').change(function(){ // you need to check that it is working or not because i don't know from where it is coming
        var value = $('#myHref').val(); // same as above check yourself.
        $.get('get_sales_price.php','',function(data){ 
            if(data ==1){
                alert('hello');
            }else{
                alert('hi');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Example 2:-**

**But if your `php` code is like below:-**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){ // check id coming from `ajax` or not
     $data = Array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**then `jquery` will be like below:-**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myHref').change(function(){
        var value = $('#myHref').val();
        $.get('get_sales_price.php','',function(data){ 
            var newdata = $.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON
            if(newdata.a ==1 && newdata.b !== 1){
                alert('hello');
            }else{
                alert('hi');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Note:- these are simple examples, but conditions will vary in `jquery`, based on returned response from `php`. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Forgot the `.done`

```
  $.get('get_projectName.php',
   {id:value}
  ).done(function(data) { 
     console.log(data)
     var data2 = JSON.parse(data);

     if(data2.abc === 1)
     {
       //Do something
     }else{
       //Else Do something
     }
  });
```

Comment: How can I use `if($abc == 1){DO SOMETHNG}`, get_projectName.php returns $abc and according to returned vale $abc i need to apply if condtion

Comment: `$.get` as a callback parameter that works fine. How is that an answer?

Comment: Can you console.log(data)?

Answer (score 2):

You can write code as below -

```
//At javscript end
$.get( "get_projectName.php", function( data ) {
   if(data == "1"){
     // do your work
   }
});
// At php end
<?php
$abc = 1;
echo $abc;
?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

- In main-php-file On change of value, Fetch the value pass it a php file sub-php-file via ajax
- In sub-php-file, echo the ouput in json format
- Retrieve the output and do the calculation

**jQuery library**, if never included

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

**ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#myHref').on('change', function(){ 
        var value = $('#myHref').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "get_projectName.php",  
                data: { id:value },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(theResponse) {

                        var abc = theResponse['abc'];

                        if (abc == 1) {
                        //Do something
                        } else {
                        //Else Do something
                        }

                    }  
            });
    });
});                 
</script>
```

**get_projectName.php**

```
<?php
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

$ReturnArray['abc'] = 1;

echo json_encode( $ReturnArray );
?>
```

Comment: OP used get so try to give answer based on get